# Where do I finde some sample Price List databases?

Tags: database, sample, price

I want to build a price list database for managing individual product pricing for individual customers with validity period and so on. So not just a article table with there prices.

I've searched for sample database, unfortunately I couldn't find one. The AdventureWorks sample database of Microsoft does not contain a pricing-module.

Does anyone know of some sample databases for pricing?

Or maybe someone knows some good books or other knowledge base resources on this topic that help?

I've searched for "price list database" and got just a few related results. 
Which search tags would be more appropriate?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a sample database for that, you kinda asked the question by yourself. 
You need 2 more tables in AdventureWorks database: `PriceList` and `PriceListXProduct`. `PriceList` with foreign key to `Customer` is used to store the validity of the prices. `PriceListXProduct` has foreign keys to `PriceList` and `Product` and contains the prices. Features can be added based on the (business) requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick help. So the logic is like logic of OrderHead and OrderPos tables with customer and product tables. That's what I also thought of but I was not sure maybe there are other important aspects and scenarios in the practice that I'm not aware of it. So I thought that some sample databases or literature on the topic may provide more insights and ideas.

So I'll start with your advice and let you know if there is complication. Thanks again.